# Backbone: filtering models from an array of names

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Have an array of id's

```
['tom','tim','joe','matt','scott']
```

Each model has an attribute that has an id.

How can I grab all 5 of the models and put in a new collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using the [underscore filter method](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) on the corresponding collection?

```
var ids = ['tom','tim','joe','matt','scott'];

var matches = collection.filter(function (model) { 
   return ids.indexOf(model.id) > -1; 
});
```

If you need to `fetch` the models from your persistence layer, you might consider generating a collection of models with the `id` attribute set and providing an appropriate endpoint to populate the other attributes:

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: MyModel, // whatever your model is
  url: '/byname'  // whatever the endpoint is
});

var models = [];

_.each(ids, function (id) {
  models.push({ id: id });
});

var collection = new MyCollection;
collection.fetch({ models: models }); // fetch the associated models
```

Whatever endpoint you provide (`/byname` in the example above) should be prepared to generate a collection containing each model whose id was specified in the `models` parameter.

Comment: The filter works perfect. For the adding to the collection. is fetching it the same as `collection.reset(models)` ?

Comment: `fetch` retrieves the collection from the server, while `reset` does a hard update of the models with whatever you pass in (no server request).